# Getting Categories data from rows in columns and matching values for actuals (y) and predicted (yhat) python

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a data frame like this, where Groups, Entity, Year they can have different categories. I have shown just one example.

```
TimePeriod  Groups  Entity  Category        Year    Quarter Predictions    Value
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q1_2022    2021    1          yhat     25379.12223
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q4_2021    2021    1          y        19915.88
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q3_2021    2021    1          y        19915.88
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q3_2021    2021    1          yhat     24199.99065
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q4_2021    2021    1          yhat     24308.29262
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q2_2021    2021    1          yhat     24627.24434
1/1/2021    CO       UK   Model_Q1_2022     2021    1          y        19915.88
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q2_2021    2021    1          y        19915.88
```

I tried `pivot_tabel`. However, it gives give me needed columns but could not match values for `yhat` and `y`

```
 df.pivot_table(index=df.columns[:-2].tolist(), columns=['Predictions'], values='Value').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

#### resulting output

```
TimePeriod  Groups  Entity  Category    Year    Quarter y   yhat
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q1_2022   2021    1   19915.88    NaN
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q1_2022   2021    1   NaN 25379.12223
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q2_2021   2021    1   19915.88    NaN
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q2_2021   2021    1   NaN 24627.24434
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q3_2021   2021    1   19915.88    NaN
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q3_2021   2021    1   NaN 24199.99065
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q4_2021   2021    1   19915.88    NaN
1/1/2021    CO  UK  Model_Q4_2021   2021    1   NaN 24308.29262
```

#### datatypes

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8 entries, 19535 to 140390
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   TimePeriod     8 non-null      object 
 1   Groups         8 non-null      object 
 2   Entity         8 non-null      object  
 5   Currency       8 non-null      object 
 6   Category       8 non-null      object 
 7   Year           8 non-null      int64  
 8   Quarter        8 non-null      int64  
 9   Predictions    8 non-null      object 
 10  Value          8 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(9)
```

I dont know how can I achive above dataframe. Maybe I have to condition of TimePeriod   / Categories. But then I can also have different Groups / Entity as well.

#### expected output

```
TimePeriod  Groups  Entity  Category        Year    Quarter    yhat       y
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q1_2022    2021    1       25379.12223 19915.88
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q2_2021    2021    1       24627.24434 19915.88
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q3_2021    2021    1       24199.99065 19915.88
1/1/2021    CO       UK    Model_Q4_2021    2021    1       24308.29262 19915.88
```

Any help / suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: the example dataframe as in question

Comment: I run your solution and get exactly expected ouput.

Comment: but i get value for say yhat but nan for y

Comment: `but i get value for say yhat but nan for y` - it means not exist `y` for `yhat` value, so pandas add `NaN`

Comment: One thing `Year` should be extracted from `Category` ? If yes, add `df['Year'] = df['Category'].str.extract('(\d{4})$')` before your solution

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If get missing values like in question problems should be:

- numeric columns are mixed strings/numbers
- string columns should contains trailing spaces
- datetimes column is mixed - strings with datetimes

Solution:

```
df[['Year','Quarters']] = df[['Year','Quarters']].astype(int)
df[['Groups','Entity','Category']] = df[['Groups','Entity','Category']].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
df['TimePeriod'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimePeriod'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: i tried this still the same output

Comment: @user3459293 Are data confidental?

Comment: no i can give you if you want

Comment: @user3459293 - Super, can you share your file? the best `df.to_pickle('data.pkl')` by gdocs, dropbox...